# Error coming when seperating kivy and py file

Tags: python, kivy

I've just started learning Python with kivymd. I'm following kivymd example and I got problems.

When I try to separate with py file and kivy file, The kivy file has an error with a red underline.

```
Kivy files require #:kivy ! [1,1]
```

Here is the image of what I have a problem with.

[image]

Comment: Please don't use an image in your question. Try writing your code and formatting it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your lint tool is incorrectly telling you that you should write `#:kivy some_version_number` at the top of your kv files. Either do that, or turn off/replace your linter, or put up with the false error.

Comment: Thanks! I just empty the first line of the kv file, so it works normally. Do you know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

I am answering the second question  (i.e. 'Do you know why this is?).  See https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#module-kivy.lang where is states that "The content of the file should always start with the Kivy header, where version must be replaced with the Kivy language version you’re using. ".   So this appears to be a requirement and therefore means the lint tool is not incorrect.  Although, I had same question and believe it is a confusing requirement because the Kivy language version is not present in most examples.    Visual Studio Code always gives me the same error.